# Get a list with tuple unpacking in a function

Tags: python, list, function, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I have a given function that takes different inputs (example):

```
def myfunction(x, y, z):
    a = x,y,z
    return a
```

Then, this for loop:

```
tripples = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'm')]
for tripple in tripples:
    lst.append(myfunction(*tripple))
lst
```

Which works like this:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'm')]
```

I want to run it for `i in range(n)` and get a list of lists as an output,

```
for i in range(3):
    for tripple in tripples:
        lst_lst.append(myfunction(*tripple))
lst_lst
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('d', 'e', 'f'),
 ('g', 'h', 'i'),
 ('j', 'k', 'm'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('d', 'e', 'f'),
 ('g', 'h', 'i'),
 ('j', 'k', 'm'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('d', 'e', 'f'),
 ('g', 'h', 'i'),
 ('j', 'k', 'm')]
```

Desired output:

```
[[('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('d', 'e', 'f'),
 ('g', 'h', 'i'),
 ('j', 'k', 'm')],
 [('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('d', 'e', 'f'),
 ('g', 'h', 'i'),
 ('j', 'k', 'm')],
 [('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('d', 'e', 'f'),
 ('g', 'h', 'i'),
 ('j', 'k', 'm')]]
```

If it helps of something, full code:

```
def myfunction(x, y, z):
    a = x,y,z
    return a

lst = []
lst_lst = []
tripples = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'm')]
for tripple in tripples:
    lst.append(myfunction(*tripple))
for i in range(3):
    for tripple in tripples:
        lst_lst.append(myfunction(*tripple))
lst_lst
```

Comment: You can just do `[tripples]*3` instead.

Comment: @wim Actual code is more complex. First statement says that the function is just an example, so `[tripples]*3` won't be enough

Comment: OK.  Is the function deterministic?  (Same input = same output)

Comment: No, inputs are different variables and it return a list, there is already an accepted answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def myfunction(x, y, z):
    a = x,y,z
    return a

lst = []
tripples = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'm')]

for i in range(3):
    lst_lst = []
    for tripple in tripples:
        lst_lst.append(myfunction(*tripple))

    lst.append(lst_lst)

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a temporary list, which saves the result of one loop and then add those result to the final  list and in next loop it intialise itself and then again save result from next triples

```
def myfunction(x, y, z):
    a = x,y,z
    return a

lst = []
lst_lst = []
tripples = [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'm')]
for tripple in tripples:
    lst.append(myfunction(*tripple))
for i in range(3):
    tmp =[]
    for tripple in tripples:
        tmp.append(myfunction(*tripple))
    lst_lst.append(tmp)
```

Comment: why do you need the first loop?

Comment: @BryanWoo i just took the OP full code and modified the later and used part. first loop can be removed, answer is in `lst_lst` list .